# Enable or disable notifications based on location on Android?

Tags: notifications, geolocation

I really wish that I could make my Android beep for business emails when at work, and home emails when I'm not in the office. Is there any applications that easily facilitates that?

Answer (score 6):

Sure are. Check out Locale or Tasker. Both are great (and very powerful) tools for customizing settings based on location, time, etc. Neither are free but are well worth a purchase.